# Store images in indexedDB using jsstore in angular5

Tags: indexeddb, angular5

I need to store **images as blob** in **indexeddb** using **jsstore**.

Is it possible? If yes, how can i achieve this in angular5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, It is possible as JsStore is build in a way to store any JS values (primitive and object).

You can use the datatype as `object` while creating the table schema for storing Blob object and can perform necessary operations on it.

*Have a look on this github project on [Image blob](https://github.com/udaychy/ImageBlobDemo) and its [live demo](https://udaychy.github.io/ImageBlobDemo/).* It will definitely give you some idea on how this works and you can change the code for your Angular 5 project accordingly.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much.I will try

Comment: Hi,I got Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in local while creating blob

Comment: Are you trying to load the image from other domain or using iframe?

Comment: that code will only work if the requested server allow CORS

Comment: One thing that you can do is to load the image using `img` tag (like we do) and then create an blob object(or base64 string ) out of it.

Comment: I fixed cors error.But response is not back from   xhr.onload = function response(e) {
               var urlCreator = window.URL ;}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162730/discussion-between-uday-and-kamalav).